# How to fix black screen after installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Asus X550VXK laptop and enable full potential of Nvidia graphics card?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

What should I do if I encounter a black screen after installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on an Asus X550VXK laptop?

I have tried the installation process several times, and each time the installation appears to run normally, but after rebooting the system, I only see a black screen.

I have found a solution that involves adding

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0 acpi=force intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

to the `/etc/default/grub` file, but I am wondering if there are alternative solutions that will allow me to use my Nvidia graphics card to its full potential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Ubuntu installation likely uses `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` the problem for you may be that it simply doesn't do it's job properly...

In that case; **installing one of the nvidia drivers from the GUI:**

Hit the Win/Super-key and type `Drivers`
a greenish icon will appear saying `Additional drivers`, click on it.

You will see a selection of nvidia driver versions. Click on one of them. Reboot: Did it work? If not try another one, I'm assuming there is more than one.

*If there is no list? Chose the `/Ubuntu software\` tab and make sure you have all but `Source` selected. Then go back to `/Additional drivers\`*

---

Doing the same from the Recovery console (Text mode):
Reboot,
Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> once as the "BIOS" text appears.
You should end up with the `grub menu`,
select the `Advanced options` alternative with the cursor keys, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
Select the topmost `Recovery mode` - It will bring up another menu.

Select the `fsck`, `networking` and then `root shell options` in that sequence.
The root shell will appear after yet another <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
you're now logged in as root (administrator) in a Bash shell.

Here make sure that there is no broken or half installed nvidia   drivers;
simply do `apt purge packagename` on them.
Then install another one with `apt install packagename`.

To display a list of INSTALLED nvidia related packages:
`$ dpkg --list | grep -E ^ii.*nvidia`

To display ALL nvidia-packages, remove `-E ^ii.*` from the above.

Answer (score 0):

Let the built-in ubuntu-drivers program decide automatically which proprietary graphics drivers to install. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

`sudo ubuntu-drivers install` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

From GRUB you can [boot in recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode). If you succeed perhaps just run an update in the terminal app.

```
apt update
```

And if it has updates,

```
apt upgrade
```

You could check for additional drivers.

From the menu search for "drivers."

Additional Drivers searches automatically.

[Additional Drivers window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00aym.png)

If you want to use the terminal run:

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

[Ubuntu drivers autoinstall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d34fO.png)